# UIWebView: several pages with horizontal scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am having a difficult time finding any information on this and I think it's because I am looking at this all wrong.

I am trying to create a `UIWebView` that has several webviews within it. The way I picture this is a `UIPageController` with dynamic pages being loaded or a scroll view that has dynamic `UIWebView`s in it so that the user can guesture left or right for "next page" and "back" operations with a nice scroll like animation to the next webview page. The problem is I can't seem to find any information on how to set this up properly and in xCode 4.2. The other part of the problem is that the number of pages is never known to the app but I can find out if there is a "next page" (currently by using javascript in the `UIWebView` and passing the new url to `[webView loadRequest:]`). Can someone point me it the right direction?